# How to avoid gdalwarp converting to alpha band

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, resampling

I am running the following code in order to resample a single-band TIFF file, whose data are going from 0 to 100 with 255 being the nodata value

```
"gdalwarp -t_srs "+srs+" -tr "+pxsz+" "+pxsz+" -te "+xmin+" "+ymin+" "+xmax+" "+ymax+" -te_srs "+srs+" -r average -srcnodata 255 -dstnodata -999 -ot Float32 -of GTiff "+fin+" "+fou
```

The problem is that the output file have a single alpha band instead of the grey original, as you can see by the gdalinfo

```
Band 1 Block=11x9 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

while the original file had

```
Band 1 Block=4830x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: There is also another odd feature: you ask gdalwarp to create a Float32 image but gdalinfo is from an 8-bit image. Did file "fou" exist already?

Comment: @user30184 fou is the output file which does not exist already. I am using Float32 in order to get the average values with comma. Does this create a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce with source data that I created with gdal_create by the information that you have given.

```
gdal_create -of GTiff -outsize 2830 3000 -co blockxsize=2830 -co blockysize=1 -bands 1 -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr 30 40 20 50 source.tif

gdalinfo source.tif
Band 1 Block=2830x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Then I used your gdalwarp command in a bit simplified format

```
gdalwarp -r average -t_srs epsg:3857 -srcnodata 255 -dstnodata -999 -ot Float32 -of GTiff source.tif target.tif
```

Gdalinfo reports the target band to present Gray, and the data type is Float32

```
gdalinfo target.tif

Band 1 Block=2375x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-999
```